# Find if values in a column are a multiple of x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID Volume 
 1   04
 1   07
 1   11
 1   01
```

I want to check if the the values in the 'volume' column are multiples of 3 and perform an action if they are not.

How would I go about doing this?

My first thought is to divide all the values by 3 and check if we get whole numbers or not. But this process does not seem to be efficient..

Comment: with `series.mod`, convert to numeric and do `df['Volume'].mod(3).eq(0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this? -

```
x =2
df['operation'] = 0
df.loc[df['Volume']%x != 0, 'operation'] = 1
df
```

or you can use `numpy where` -

```
import numpy as np
df['operation'] = np.where(df['Volume']%x != 0, "Do something", "Do another thing”) # on left hand side just specify the column on which you wanna perform operation
```

If you’ve multiple if/else condition better use `np.select`

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the dataframe:

```
df[df['Volume']%3 != 0]
```

And then apply your actions to the filtered dataframe.